# Add more detail powershell command output

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running a Windows 2008 R2 Standard server I found a Powershell command that show me all the user account that will expire within 30 day.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
```

I would it to add the date the user will expire to the output of the command is this in anyway possible?

Comment: Have you tried piping the output of the `Where-Object` to `Get-Member` instead of `Format-Table`? That would tell you what information is available.

Comment: Jeff, i'm new to this can you show me a example?

Comment: `Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' } | Get-Member` will show you what information is in the object that `Search-ADAccount` returns. As a simple example, `Get-Process` returns objects of type `System.Diagnostics.Process`; if I select a single process on my computer and pipe it to Get-Member `Get-Process -Name CCMExec | Get-Member` I will get a list of properties and methods that an object of type `System.Diagnostic.Process` supports. There are too many to paste here; there will be many for an ActiveDirectory object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the fields to output, change (for now) to `Select-Object *` to get all fields.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 |
  Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} |
  Select-Object * |
  Format-Table -Autosize
```

I've also expanded on the aliases/abbreviated commands and put each pipeline section on a new line.

Once you can see all the available columns, change this line...

```
  Select-Object * |
```

...to

```
  Select-Object FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 |
```

...where `FIELD1-3` represent the columns you want to see in the output.

And to get help on the `Search-ADAccount` function, use PowerShell's help command, like this:

```
Get-Help Search-ADAccount -Full
```

You may need to use this in combination with `Get-ADUser` to get the account expiration details.

Comment: It almost works how I want it, can't seem to find how to show the experation date of the user.

Comment: Use the PowerShell `Get-Help` command, like this: `Get-Help Search-ADAccount -Full`. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | select -First 1 | Format-List * -Force
```

That should give you a list of all properties of the returned object, which you can then add to your `FT` command, like

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | FT Name,ObjectClass,AccountExpiring -A
```

Comment: It almost works how I want it, can't seem to find how to show the experation date of the user.